# Changing Rails DB while Keeping Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, models

I'm in the mioddle of a Rails project right now and the model and database layers continue to evolve. This is a pain since I haven't set up automatically seeded data yet (I know), and adding columns and relations kills my older data's utility. The controller/view don't mind nil values, but the older objects are complaining that they don't have the methods.

Is there anyway to update the old data and just give them nil values for the new attrs and relations?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly you could either use an SQL statement on the old items, something like "update table set old_attr = NULL where ..."
You could also use "rails c" and do something like... "User.all.each{ |user| user.name = nil; user.save! }

Comment: There are several thoughts that come to mind, including default values in the migrations and updating the models, but it's not clear what the actual issues are.  Can you provide a some code or specific examples of what's causing problems?